# Why does "s" have different forms?

Tags: old-english, typography, paleography

Why does "s" in the [Bath Old English Gospels](https://parker.stanford.edu/parker/catalog/ks656dq8163) (p. 10) have different forms?

[image: Two s shapes: one looks like modern lowercase r and the other looks like modern lowercase f]

*soþlice **s**e **s**teorra*
and, lo, the star (Matthew 2:9)

Comment: The long ſ disappeared from English printing and handwriting about 1800 or so. You can tell from the dated example sentences in the OED.

Comment: @JohnLawler The insular low ꞅ shown in the image also disappeared long ago. Same with the many other insular forms like ꞃ.

Comment: It might be a coincidence, but ancient and modern [Greek alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet) has two forms of S, although the use doeesn't match that in older English.

Comment: This isn't really an English question since these typographical variants were present in other languages, e.g. [these proceedings of a French society from the 18th century](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5803201z/f753.image).

Comment: @LukeSawczak: the typographic "long s" was present in many Continental European languages. The "low s" or "[insular s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insular_S)" at the start of *se* was, I think, not so widespread (and I'm not sure if it was ever commonly used in type).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "s" at the start of "se" and the one at the start of "steorra"  are two variant handwritten forms of the same letter. I don't think the use of one vs. the other is connected to any difference in meaning. It might be affected by the following letter: apparently the taller version of *s* seen in *steorra* might be preferred as part of an *st* ligature. (The letters *st* are not connected to each other in the picture you have there, but I guess there's a little bit of overlap in the horizontal space occupied by each letter: I'm not sure if that's all that the quote below is referring to when it talks about an *st* ligature, or if there is some other, more blatantly ligatured variant.)

I remembered seeing a similar looking "s" to the one shown in "se" in J. R. R. Tolkien's handwriting.
Googling his name, I found this article, "[‘Written in a Fair Hand’: The Living Tradition of Medieval Scripts in J.R.R. Tolkien’s Calligraphy](https://scholar.valpo.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1192&context=journaloftolkienresearch)" (Eduardo B. Kumamoto, *Journal of Tolkien Research,* Volume 10, Issue 2, Article 8, 2020), which shows these figures and provides the following labels that I think fit, "low *s*" for the version seen in "se" and "long *s*" for the version seen in "steorra":

[image: Figure 3, captioned "Detail of the 1939 sheet of minutes showing insular letterforms." Image: handwritten text saying "by the anglosaxon bookhand". The S in "saxon" is written with a "low s".]

> Also noticeable in Figure 3 is the letter *s* in *Anglosaxon,* diving deep under the base line. This form is called by Lockett (2002: 164) “low *s*” and, according to her, it is conspicuous in the Exodus manuscript because of its consistent use, that is, the scribe did not employ any variation of the letter. In other manuscripts, the low form of letter *s* coexisted with other ones, such as the “long *s*”, which was often ligatured with the following letter, as it happens in the *Exeter Book* (Conner 2015: 309). Tolkien also imitated the long *s* in the last line of the 1939 manuscript, in the word *style* (Figure 4):

[image: Figure 4, captioned "Detail of the 1939 sheet of minutes showing the 'long s' and 'tall e'."]
(page 13)

The references that Kumamoto cites here are

- > Lockett, Leslie. 2002. ‘An integrated re-examination of the dating of Oxford, Bodleian Library, Junius 11’, *Anglo-Saxon England,* 31, 141–73
- > Conner, Patrick W. 2015. ‘The Structure of the Exeter Book Codex’, in Mary P. Richards (ed.). *Anglo-Saxon Manuscripts: Basic Readings* (New York: Routledge), pp. 301–16

Lockett says

> Junius 11’s Scribe 1 is very unusual among tenth-century English scribes in his absolute adherence to one form of **s**, the low form. Tall **s** is entirely absent, while round **s** is never used as a minuscule form but only as a capital. It does not seem that we can attach chronological significance to this phenomenon, because from early in the tenth century, some scribes reserved certain forms of **s** for Latin texts,<sup>111</sup> but the usual practice was to alternate among two or three of the available forms, employing tall-**s** ligatures in the appropriate circumstances.<sup>112</sup>
> [...]
>
> 111 Ker, *Catalogue,* p. xxx.
>
> 112 Ker does not discuss tall-**s** ligatures in detail, but common ones include initial **s** with **p**, **t** and
> **wynn**.

(page 164)

Our moderator [tchrist♦](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist) has left a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/608435/why-does-s-have-different-forms/608438#comment1537861_608435) showing that the  Unicode letter named "latin small letter insular s" (U+A785) takes the form of a "low *s*": ꞅ. This symbol has a [Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%9E%85) which suggests, in agreement with my suspicions, that the use of ꞅ vs. ſ could be related to the following letter, although the pattern Wiktionary describes ("Lower-case *ꞅ* may be used before vowels, contrasting with long-ess *ſ* before consonants and round *s* at the ends of words") doesn't fit with the use of "ſ" rather than "ꞅ" before "o" in the word "ſoþlice" in your picture.

I followed the link and tried to see if I could determine the pattern followed by the scribe who wrote Matthew in the *Bath Old English Gospels.* I see examples of "ſt" and "ſƿ" in the Old English text, but although also "ꞅt" at the end of a word in "bꞃinᵹꞅt" *bringst* and "ᵹeþencᵹꞅt" *geþencgst*, and "ꞅƿ" at the start of a word in "ꞅƿa" *swa*. At the end of a word or before vowels, I'm not sure what principle if any governs the use of "ꞅ" vs. "ſ"; my impression is that "ꞅ" is usual in the Old English text but "ſ" seems to have a greater frequency in the red Latin bits. I would guess that the usage of these variants in this text follows trends but not a strict rule (similar to the variation between þ and ð).

Comment: Interesting, the Anglosaxon bookhand. :)

Comment: Is there a text version of the Bath Old English Gospels that doesn't use regular "s" for all the forms? It would be interesting to do an automated analysis.

Comment: @Laurel: Good idea! I'm not sure if there is one, though.

Answer (score -2):

[English is a Germanic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_languages), and that came into English from its German roots and was what was called a [long s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s). Nowadays, you only find the long s when it is combined with the short s, or just s, in German to form the *eszett* or *scharfes s* ([ẞ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)), the long s you mention forming the back and beginning top arch of what sort of looks like a B and the s starting at the end of that arch.

So, it's not a different spelling but a different character that is no longer used as [it was dropped when it was combined with the short s](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/english-language-and-linguistics/article/abs/longs-in-late-modern-english-manuscripts/978CC5E6B0C576751E201F4DD36CDD9F), or just s, in English since [their pronunciation in English came to be the same.](https://library.csun.edu/SCA/Peek-in-the-Stacks/esses#:%7E:text=One%20lower%2Dcase%20letter%20we,beginning%20and%20middle%20of%20words.)

Comment: I think the question is asking why the "s" at the start of "se" and the "s" at the start of "steorra" look different in the picture. (the one at the start of "se" looks more like an "r", to my eyes.)

Comment: I answered that question in the first paragraph, namely because it's a long S, not a short S. The long S, which sounded like a cross between an S and an F, came to be pronounced the same as the short S, so it was dropped in English and combined with the short S, what we just call S today, the gist of which is my second paragraph.

Comment: You're misreading your source. All forms of S (`ſ`, `s`, `ꞅ`) were the same letter, and were purely used for visual/aesthetic reasons (similar to how letters look different in cursive depending on their surrounding letters or how we have single- and double-story letters). Most pronunciation guides don't even list long S ([example](https://people.umass.edu/sharris/in/gram/GrammarBook/Pronunciation.html), [exception](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Old_English/F%C5%8Drespr%C7%A3c)) — readers are expected to know they're the same letter.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: was the long s ever pronounced differently in English? I know it was in some languages, but as far as I know, there's only been one /s/ in English since Old English.